# ZonedDateTime.parse bug?

Tags: java, scala, java-time

Given a `ZonedDateTime`, calling `toString` then `ZonedDateTime.parse` returns a different time in some cases.

Here is a specific example. Code is in Scala but it's no different in Java.

```
import java.time._

val t = 1193534827725L
val z = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")

val a = Instant.ofEpochMilli(t).atZone(z) // 2007-10-28T02:27:07.725+01:00[Europe/Paris]
val b = ZonedDateTime.parse(a.toString)   // 2007-10-28T02:27:07.725+02:00[Europe/Paris]
a == b // returns false!
```

The re-parsed value also has a different epochMilli:

```
scala> List(a, b).map(_.toInstant.toEpochMilli)
res46: List[Long] = List(1193534827725, 1193531227725)

scala> List(a, b).map(_.toInstant.toEpochMilli == t)
res47: List[Boolean] = List(true, false)
```

Using `.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)` instead of `.toString` doesn't work either.

According to the Javadoc for `Instant#atZone` which defers to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-

> Converting an instant to a zoned date-time is simple as there is only
>   one valid offset for each instant.

What's going on?

**Edit:** It's also worth mentioning that daylight savings occurred around the sample time ([ref](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2007)) such that there were two instances of `02:27:07.725`. As you can see from `.toString` the offset is correct but parsing doesn't seem to respect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in Java 9.

See [JDK-8066982](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066982): *ZonedDateTime.parse() returns wrong ZoneOffset around DST fall transition*

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this fix was applied to 9 and not 8?

Comment: No, I just did a google search to find the registered bug. BTW: You could have done the search yourself faster than writing the question here.

Comment: Bug fixes go to 9 first, then 8. See backport issue - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149540